# Why does this proof points out that $AB=AC$ and $AC=AB$?

Tags: geometry

I am reading the following proof on Coxeter's Introduction to Geometry:

> [image]

Why does he points out that $AB=AC$ and $AC=AB$? Isn't equality reflexive? Could we have $AB=AC$ and $AC\not=AB$?

Answer (score 3):

He starts the proof remarking: "Let us conceive this triangle as two triangles". Try to think of the second triangle as $ A'B'C' $. With this change the two equalities become
$ AB = A'C' $ and $ AC = A'B' $.

Answer (score 1):

AB=AC and AC=AB are not related to each other. This is just the "S","S" part of the SAS.